# DAX: Monthly AVG

Tags: powerbi, dax

I am looking for the "best practice" when it comes to calculating Monthly Averages in DAX. Ideally, I would like to use some of the DAX built in Time Intelligence Functions.

I have a measure called "Total Units". `Total Units = COUNT(Table[UnitId])`

Each row in my table represents when a single unit was sold.

When I put my Total Units and Sales Date into a bar chart, I can see how many units were sold every month.

How do I now calculate the monthly average?

```
Month         Total Units (Sold)
Jan 2019      10
Feb 2019      30
```

I want a measure that will tell me that the Monthly AVG is **(10+30)/2 = 20**

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There are a couple of ways to solve this. Assuming you have a [Month] column on your table, you could simply do:

```
MonthlyAvg = DIVIDE ( [Total Units] , DISTINCTCOUNT( 'Table'[Month] ) )
```

In other words, simply dividing the total with the number of months considered.

If you have a more "proper" data model, with a separate calendar dimension, you should do something like:

```
MonthlyAvg = AVERAGEX( VALUES( 'Calendar'[Month] ) , [Total Units] )
```

Comment: Thank you for the solution. I went ahead with your AVERAGEX function and it worked perfectly.

Answer (score 0):

All you need is a simple average measure as below,

```
Total Avg = AVERAGE(Total Units (Sold))
```

When you select any period for date, measure will adjust and provide the average for the selection.

Let's say you select for year 2019 and Months are Jan, Feb, March

> (Jan + Feb + March)/3

Hope it helps!!

Comment: I can't use the Average function on a Measure. Total Units is a measure that is derived from COUNT(Table[unitID])

Comment: I see, try AverageX('Your Table', Total Units(Sold))... Though I don't have any dataset to verify your ask.